# How I can write AverageSum.java different console inputs?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, average

Can anyone tell me how I can write java code for the average of the variables in case the input has a different number of variables each time?I assume that the elementary case of the problem can be solved with the help of a for loop and as long as a loop without reaching arrays.

Comment: Could you show us the code you have tried?

Comment: At the moment I have not written code, because I haven't idea how I can to begin

Comment: In that case it might be better to read a book on Java or follow some beginner tutorials. StackOverflow is a place where you can get help, but not where we teach basic programming.

Comment: I am currently taking a basic java programming course. My experience is in c# and I am currently trying to improve my qualification in java. The opportunity to communicate with people like you who have similar interests is very important to me, and I hope I can be useful to you too and your community.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like that ?

```java
public class Average {
    public static void main(String... arguments) {
        double average = Stream.of(arguments)
            .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
            .average()
            .orElse(0d);
        System.out.println(average);
    }
}
```

Exemple usage:

```
$ java Average 5 6 10 15 57
18.6
```

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            sum = sum + number;
        }
        System.out.println(sum / n);
    }
}

Comment: I'm grateful for the correct answer from your side, but I still can't declare a class, so I'm resorting to simpler methods.

Comment: What exactly are the constraints of the problem? Is it a constraint that the user has to input the numbers on separate lines in the terminal?

Comment: Is it possible for the user to input the numbers directly as arguments to the program? For instance: `java Average 5 6 10 15 57`? If that is legal you can just put the implementation I gave in the `main` method

Comment: @lolo101 In that case you would still need to parse the String arguments as doubles

Comment: @AdriaanKoster yes sure, it would juste be a matter of `Double.parse(...)`

Comment: Just changed my code so you have a MainClass ;)